# Создать тип Matrix, инкапсулирующий двумерный массив-матрицу блок реального (двойного) типа на c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

У меня есть задание,Создать тип Matrix, инкапсулирующий двумерный массив-матрицу
блок реального (двойного) типа. В своем коде я дошла только до половины. И теперь топчусь на месте. Вот что мне удалось решить :

````
```
  using System;
    
    namespace MatrixLibrary
    {
        class MatrixException : Exception
        {
            public int Rows { get; }
            public int Columns { get; }
    
            public override string Message
            {
                get
                {
                    return "incorrect quantity of rows/columns";
                }
            }
            public MatrixException(int rows, int columns)
            {
                this.Rows = rows;
                this.Columns = columns;
            }
    
        }
        // TODO: Create custom exception "MatrixException"
    
        public class Matrix : ICloneable
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Number of rows.
            /// </summary>
            public int Rows
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Number of columns.
            /// </summary>
            public int Columns
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets an array of floating-point values that represents the elements of this Matrix.
            /// </summary>
            public double[,] Array
            {
                get; set;
            }
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Matrix"/> class.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="rows"></param>
            /// <param name="columns"></param>
            /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException"></exception>
            public Matrix(int rows, int columns)
            {
                Rows = rows;
                Columns = columns;
                Array = new double[Rows, Columns];
            }
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Matrix"/> class with the specified elements.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="array">An array of floating-point values that represents the elements of this Matrix.</param>
            /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
            public Matrix(double[,] array)
            {
                this.Rows = array.GetLength(0);
                this.Columns = array.GetLength(1);
                this.Array = array;
            }
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Allows instances of a Matrix to be indexed just like arrays.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="row"></param>
            /// <param name="column"></param>
            /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
            public double this[int row, int column]
            {
                get
                {
    
                    return this.Array[row, column];
                }
                set
                {
    
                    this.Array[row, column] = value;
                }
            } 
```
````

теперь я пытаюсь решить вот этот :

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a deep copy of this Matrix.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A deep copy of the current object.</returns>
        public object Clone()
        {

           // if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;


            //var other = (Matrix)obj;
           // return (this.rows == other.rows) && (this.columns == other.columns);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds two matrices.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="matrix1"></param>
        /// <param name="matrix2"></param>
        /// <returns>New <see cref="Matrix"/> object which is sum of two matrices.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="MatrixException"></exception>
        public static Matrix operator +(Matrix matrix1, Matrix matrix2)
        {
           // Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(matrix1, row, colum);
           // Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix(matrix2, row, colum);

           // Boolean result;

            // result is true.
            //result = (matrix1 == matrix2);

            // result is false.
            //result = (matrix1 != matrix2);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Subtracts two matrices.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="matrix1"></param>
        /// <param name="matrix2"></param>
        /// <returns>New <see cref="Matrix"/> object which is subtraction of two matrices</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="MatrixException"></exception>
        public static Matrix operator -(Matrix matrix1, Matrix matrix2)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Multiplies two matrices.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="matrix1"></param>
        /// <param name="matrix2"></param>
        /// <returns>New <see cref="Matrix"/> object which is multiplication of two matrices.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="MatrixException"></exception>
        public static Matrix operator *(Matrix matrix1, Matrix matrix2)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds <see cref="Matrix"/> to the current matrix.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="matrix"><see cref="Matrix"/> for adding.</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="MatrixException"></exception>
        public Matrix Add(Matrix matrix)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Subtracts <see cref="Matrix"/> from the current matrix.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="matrix"><see cref="Matrix"/> for subtracting.</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="MatrixException"></exception>
        public Matrix Subtract(Matrix matrix)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Multiplies <see cref="Matrix"/> on the current matrix.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="matrix"><see cref="Matrix"/> for multiplying.</param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="MatrixException"></exception>
        public Matrix Multiply(Matrix matrix)
        {
            Matrix result = matrix.Multiply(array);

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tests if <see cref="Matrix"/> is identical to this Matrix.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">Object to compare with. (Can be null)</param>
        /// <returns>True if matrices are equal, false if are not equal.</returns>
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override int GetHashCode() => base.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

у меня ничего не выходит. нужна помощь

---

```
 if (matrix1.Columns == matrix2.Columns)
                for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.Rows; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < matrix1.Columns; j++)
                    {
                        matrix1.Array[i, j] = matrix1.Array[i, j] + matrix2.Array[0, j];
                    }
                }

            return matrix1;-этот код работает. я ошиблась в параметрах. нужно было с заглавной буквы
```

---

```
 public static Matrix operator +(Matrix matrix1, Matrix matrix2)
        {
            if (matrix1.Columns != matrix2.Columns && matrix1.Rows != matrix2.Rows)
                throw new ArgumentException("Количества столбцов и колонок должны быть равны");

            double[,] result = new double[matrix1.Columns, matrix1.Rows];
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.Rows; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix1.Columns; j++)
                    result[i, j] = matrix1.Array[i, j] + matrix2.Array[i, j];

            return new Matrix(result);
        }
```

я изменила код но тесты не проходят

---

```
public static Matrix operator +(Matrix matrix1, Matrix matrix2)
        {
            if (matrix1.column == matrix2.column)
                for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.row; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < matrix1.column; j++)
                    {
                        matrix1.array[i, j] = matrix1.array[i, j] + matrix2.array[0, j];
                    }
                }
            else Console.WriteLine("Количества столбцов должны быть равны");
            return matrix1;
        }
```

что тут делаю не так?

Comment: Во первых, если вам надо инкапсулировать массив, то сам массив должен быть приватным, а не публичным. Во вторых, если у вас количество строк и столбцов - изменяемые свойства, то массив надо под эти изменения подгонять, или делать эти поля только для чтения.

Comment: Не удивительно, что не выходит. Ведь чтобы вышло, надо попытаться что то сделать, а у вас ничего кроме `throw new NotImplementedException();` нету.

Comment: Почему ничего нету? Все что написано выше-все тесты прошло... и пару закоментированных параментров, которые  не прошли

Comment: Во-первых ПУБЛИЧНЫЙ массив- это то что задано в файле- СКЕЛЕТОН И МЕНЯТЬ НЕЛЬЗЯ. это можно было понять по TODO   в файле. И throw new NotImplementedException();- это параметры самого скелетона.... мой код,который работает-написан выше, Вы смотрели не туда. Вы смотрели то,на чем я запнулась

Comment: Какие то файлы, скелетоны - вы о чем вообще? У вас есть текст вопроса и код, вот туда я и глядел. Ваши методы, которые работают, меня не интересовали, у вам же по ним нет вопросов. Но вот я смотрю на остальной ваш код, и там не вижу ничего. Например, в методе клонирования нет ничего про клонирование. В методе сложения - ничего про сложение. И так далее. Вот я вам и написал, что помогать то не с чем - у вас там кода нет. Вы же не предлагаете за вас сидеть решать ваше задание?

Comment: Так я и говорю -что там где ничего нет-я не смогла решить правильно. Привела структуру файла. У меня нет технического вуза,все что я помню по данной теме-это школьный материал. Прошу сильно не кидаться помидорами )

Comment: Да я и не кидаюсь. Тут не нужен технический вуз. Вот вам надо, например, сложить 2 матрицы. Вы это можете на листочке карандашом сделать? Вот сделайте пару раз и потом попробуйте этот алгоритм в код перевести. Ну или можете сразу код загуглить, там сложного ничего нет.

Comment: Вот мое решение public Matrix Multiply(Matrix matrix)
        {
            Matrix result = matrix.Multiply(array);

            return result;
        } для мультиплей-не верно

Comment: Вот и складывание что-то делаю пока не так

Comment: Еще раз большое спасибо за ответ!

Comment: `Multiply(Matrix matrix) { Matrix result = matrix.Multiply(array);` у вас метод вызывает сам себя. Так это не заработает. Вы из математики знаете как умножать матрицы? Алгоритма умножения матриц я у вас не вижу нигде, а он должен быть.

Comment: я знаю как перемножать матрицы, но не совсем понятно как это реализовать в виде кода.попытки кода были не верны. вот попытки клонирования-тоже не верны -  public object Clone()
        {

           // if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;


            var other = (Matrix)obj;
           return (this.rows == other.rows) && (this.columns == other.columns);
        }

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < c.Rows; i++)
   for (int j = 0; j < c.Columns; j++)
   {
      c[i, j] = 0;
      for (int k = 0; k < a.Columns; k++)
         c[i, j] += a[i, k] * b[k, j];
   }-примерно так я вижу это в коде((

Comment: конечно ваши попытки клонирования неверны. Вот что такое клонирование по вашему? Вот если взять овцу и клонировать её, что получится? Наверное новая овца, полностью идентичная оригиналу, так? А если клонировать матрицу? Наверное новая матрица с новым масивом внутри, который будет полной копией оригинала, так? А у вас что?

Comment: коды ваш добавояйте в вопрос, и укажите, что в нем конкртено не так. В комментариях код невозможно читать